# spring-boot plain jdbc with mysql (no jpa)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I want to create a spring-boot project using plain jdbc as descripted here : https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/.

I would like to use a mysql database instead of the h2 of the guide. Here are my config files :

> build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-relational-data-access'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: '2.1.0.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '2.1.0.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.47'


    testCompile("junit:junit")
```

> application.properties

```
# DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring-jdbc?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

> Application

```
package hello;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        log.info("Creating tables");

        jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE customers IF EXISTS");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE customers(" +
                "id SERIAL, first_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255))");

        // Split up the array of whole names into an array of first/last names
        List<Object[]> splitUpNames = Arrays.asList("John Woo", "Jeff Dean", "Josh Bloch", "Josh Long").stream()
                .map(name -> name.split(" "))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Use a Java 8 stream to print out each tuple of the list
        splitUpNames.forEach(name -> log.info(String.format("Inserting customer record for %s %s", name[0], name[1])));

        // Uses JdbcTemplate's batchUpdate operation to bulk load data
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO customers(first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?)", splitUpNames);

        log.info("Querying for customer records where first_name = 'Josh':");
        jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE first_name = ?", new Object[] { "Josh" },
                (rs, rowNum) -> new Customer(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("first_name"), rs.getString("last_name"))
        ).forEach(customer -> log.info(customer.toString()));
    }
}
```

But the project fail to start and suggest :
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' in your configuration.

What could I do?

Comment: May be you not update project in IDE. Try run with `./gradlew bootRun` command

Comment: somehow there is no bean initalization occured .Can you please update yourcomplete  error message.Because there might be multiple reasons behind that ,which can be clarified after seeing complete error message.

Comment: you were right @NickSavenia, after a refresh in my eclipse ide, the error didn't occured anymore, tks!